# How to center align grid columns (col-md-4 & col-md-8)

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-modal

I am using Bootstrap to create a user profile page where the image is on the left-hand side and users details on the right-hand side.

I used it in the following way:

```
<div class="row">

        <!-- Col 1 -->

        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
          <div>
               <img ..>
               <h2>Name of the user</h2>
               Sample text<br>
               <a href="#"><img src="..."></a>
               <a href="#"><img src="..."></a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Col 2 -->

        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
          <div>
               <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li>...</li>
               </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Below the image of the user, it will have his/her name, followed by his/her active participation in the community, and then followed by link to his/her social media.

When I view it in desktop, it looks good. However, when I try to view it in mobile devices, the first column entire content align left. I want it to align center so it looks proper. How can I do that? Or am I making any mistake?

Comment: Okay I got a way to center the text content by using 'text-center' class. but the image is still aligned left when viewed in mobile devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class that you need is `center-block`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that for the img tag. It now aligns everything in the center on normal desktop view. But I am still facing the problem when viewing through mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `col-xs-4` CSS class in the DIVs:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
```

This way, the behavior in mobile devices will be the same of desktop.

Comment: Tried that but doesn't make much difference. I tried a few other combination of grid but still it is the same. The user image, name, etc still aligns left.

Comment: Did you try to put `col-xs-offset-2` in first column too?

Comment: ntroccoli and Raphael ... I finally got it working. Thank you!